# How can I build connection between window 10 and linux in vmware without turning on VPN?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, ftp, arch-linux, vmware-workstation

I am using windows 10.

I have installed ArchLinux on my VMware workstation.

I want to build connection between windows and linux.

I use cuteftp and flashftp to connect.  But not working with the following error message:

```
STATUS:>    [2019-09-30 20:43:01] Connecting to FTP server... 192.168.106.128:21 (ip = 192.168.106.128)...
ERROR:>     [2019-09-30 20:43:01] Can't connect to remote server. Socket error = #10013.
```

However, if VPN software is turned on, the ftp connection is successfully built.

I want to build connection when VPN is not on.

How can I solve that issue?

Comment: Have you considered SSH or Samba _(Ensure SMB/CIFS v1.0 is disabled on Windows via Add or Remove features Control Panel)_

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I just wonder why things work after I switch on VPN apps on windows 10.

Comment: There's no way an SSH connection wouldn't work if correctly configured... It sounds like a firewall issue all around [PC, server, and/or router(s)] and is where I'd start for troubleshooting.